# Create View for "One to many" in the same page in .Net MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

The question I have is:

Suppose, i have a Parent Model which has many Child Models (one to many).

Parent Model

```
public class Parent
{
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public virtual Icollection<Child> Child {get: set:}
}
```

Child Model

```
public class Child
{
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public int ParentID {get; set;}
     public virtual Parent parent {get: set:}
}
```

I have a "Create" view (through ParentController), and i want the user to state how many Children he wants to create for that particular Parent in that same view. (clicks on "add Child" and gets the Child create partial view added.

The way i think this will happen, is using a partial view for child view, and calling it using ajax in the parent/create view, and then taking the input and saving it in the parent create (post) view, but i don't know how to exactly accomplish this.

This link is the closest to what i desire, but for some reason it wouldn't run for me.

http://www.itorian.com/2013/04/nested-collection-models-in-mvc-to-add.html

Comment: Please post what you have done so far? (code wise)

Answer (score 1):

Using AJAX to load a partial is not an optimal way to handle this scenario. In particular, when working with collections, your field names need to end up in the format of `ListProperty[index].Property` in order for the modelbinder to correctly interpret the post data. If you just render a partial form for an instance of `Child`, your field names will just be the property, without any context about the name of the list property on the parent or the proper index. When rendering fields existing instances you can simply use a `for` loop:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Child.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Child[i].Name)
    ...
}
```

Based on the context of `m.Child[i].Name`, Razor can generate a correct field name. However, since you're adding new entries client-side, via JavaScript, there's no involvement with Razor.

As a result, a far better approach is to use some sort of JS library that allows data binding with your UI and supports templating. I use Knockout.js for this kind of stuff, for the most part, but Angular or perhaps something like Backbone could work as well. Just use whatever works for you.

With Knockout, for example, I can actually build a client-side "view model" JavaScript for a JSON encoded version of my MVC view model:

```
var data = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

var MyViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

    // additional observables, etc. 

    return self;
}

var viewModel = MyViewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

With that I can instantiate a JS data structure that actually has a list of children that I can add to or remove from to dynamically affect the HTML on the page.

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'ChildTemplate', foreach: Child }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="ChildTemplate">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name, attr: { name: 'Child[' + $index() + '].Name' }">
    <!-- other fields -->
</script>
```

Knockout then automatically renders a set of all the HTML in that template for each child in the list.

There's a little bit more to this in terms of how to add new child items, handle observables for the child items, etc., but a lot of that depends on what library you end up going with. All I'm really doing here is just illustrating how you would use JavaScript to dynamically added correctly indexed items to a page using basically a client-side view model and some templates. This is going to be infinitely easier and more robust than trying to cobble together some solution using AJAX to just fetch some rendered HTML.

Comment: Would you still consider this best practice for the create view/form for the parent of a one-to-many model in a razor page?
Sorry for reviving such an old post but just wanted to check if a pre-built or scaffolded solution for embedding a "dynamic" form like this exists.